# How inject a service using angularjs 1.5 es6

Tags: angularjs

I how to call a method from my service in my controller for a specific component like this

```
import template from './tech.html'
import styles from './styles.mcss'
import TechService from './techService';

class Controller {

  constructor(TechService) {
    // css modules
    TechService.consoleLog();

    this.styles = styles;
  }
}

export const tech = {
  template,
  bindings: {
    tech: '<'
  },
  controller: Controller
};
```

this it not works where should I inject and how to inject TechService

this controller is a component of this module

```
import angular from 'angular';

import {tech} from './tech';
import {techs} from './techs';
export const techsModule = 'techs';

angular
  .module(techsModule, [])
  .component('fountainTech', tech)
  .component('fountainTechs', techs);
```

and the root of my app is this

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import ngAnimate from 'angular-animate'
import ngTouch from 'angular-touch'
import uiBootstrap from 'angular-ui-bootstrap';

import {componentsModule} from './components';
import {commonModule} from './common';
import {techsModule} from './techs'
import TechService from './techs/techService';

import routesConfig from './routes';

import './index.scss';


angular
    .module('myApp', [
        // dependencies
        uiRouter, ngAnimate, ngTouch, uiBootstrap,

        // modules
        componentsModule,
        commonModule,
        techsModule
    ])
    .config(routesConfig);
```

I want to know where to inject and how my service TechService to call my method consoleLog()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use array notation:

```
export const tech = {
  template,
  bindings: {
    tech: '<'
  },
  controller: ['TechService', Controller]
};
```

Comment: how angularjs will know the string ('TechService') should I add TechService in a module TechModule as a service ?

Comment: I see that `techsModule` is already part of the app module, so it will be fine.